# Debugging DLLRegisterServer

Tags: visual-c++, dll, com, registration

I have a COM DLL built using a script. There is no Visual studio project available. When I register the dll using the command regsvr32 "`c:\windows\system32\dllname.dll`" no message is displayed.

I added a **DebugBreak()** in the function **DllRegisterServer** and also in DllMain to expect a debug dialog to be displayed. However nothing happened.

The entries expected from the DLL are NOT added to the registry.

Any suggestions on what could be missing for the DLL to register correctly and why no message is displayed.

How do I debug this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DebugBreak` breaks under debugger and crashes process which is not being debugged.

What you need is to set up Visual Studio, under C++ Project settings, Debugging, so that it starts C:\Windows\system32\regsvr32.exe with your DLL, i.e. `"$(TargetPath)"` or full path explicitly. Start debugging and your breakpoints will be hit.

Note that in 64-bit OS to debug 32-bit DLL you will need C:\Windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe.

UPD. The fact that no Visual Studio project is available is not really an obstacle. A fake project to just launch debugging session with proper command line is going to work out fine.

Other than that if you are still able to update the source code, you can add a `MessageBox` into `DllRegisterServer`, esp. instead of `DebugBreak`, start COM registration, have the message box popped up, then attach Visual Studio debugger (without need to have VS project), set breakpoints and then close the message box to let the execution continue and reach the points of interest.

Comment: He says no VS project available.

Comment: I added a **AfxMessageBox**, but this did not show up. Other things tried were
1. Check whether the `regsvr32` is executing using process explorer. It came for a very short time and vanished.
2. Opened the dll using Dependency viewer and the DLL functions are displayed correctly. The DLL is not corrupted.

Comment: Is your DLL using any dependencies whcih are not avaialble? In this case DLL would not load. Not sure about `AfxMessageBox`, can you try `MessageBox` instead, this is pure API without MFC layer. Also you might want to put this into `DllMain`, maybe crashing is there. If none of these helps, why don't you start full process under debugger as originally suggested, enable break on exception and see where the problem is.

Comment: @RomanR. I found that I was using the older version of the software and upgraded it- possible dependency issur. Now the DLL is giving an error message when registering. The message is `Loadlibrary(lib.dll) failed - One or more arguments are invalid`

Comment: @RomanR. The DLL is working fine now.  
Problems:  
1. Dependency with some other DLL (I don't know what).  
2. Putting an `AfxMessageBox` in the DllMain - This caused the message `one or more arguments are invalid`.

Comment: I was having the same problem (trying to debug DllRegisterServer and the debugger not starting). @RomanR.'s answer is correct, but I found I had to specify the full path the regsvr32.exe before the debugger would actually work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found RegSvrEx very helpful in these situations. It gives a much better diagnostic output and because you have the source you can attach a debugger.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3505/RegSvrEx-An-Enchanced-COM-Server-Registration-Util